# Amount of steam generated using gas burner and Induction cooker

Tags: experimental-physics, evaporation

I did an experiment by boiling water using two different heat sources. 
At first, I boiled water using a gas stove, then I repeated by using an induction cooker.
I noticed that the amount of steam (visible vapour) formed is not the same. 
When using induction cooker, I could see a massive amount of steam but very little when I boil water using gas burner. 
For both cases, I`m using the same pot size and the room condition is the same. 
I'm interested to know why there is different in steam formed.

Comment: Lots of standard induction cooktops can easily put out much more power than a typical gas cooktop. Could the difference in the amount of steam you're seeing simply be explained by the fact that the induction cooktop may be boiling off water at a significantly faster rate than the gas cooktop?

Comment: Hi Samuel, the induction cooktops that i`m using is only 7kw. But the capacity of the gas burner that i`m using in this test is about 40kw, commercial high pressure gas burner. The purpose i`m carry out this test is i thought that it could generate more visible steam using gas burner because the power is much higher. But it turned out another way.

Answer (score 2):

We can only guess since we can't study your experimental setup in detail, and my guess would be that the combustion of gas generates a large volume of hot gas that flows upwards past your pan, while an induction hob generates a much smaller air flow due to heating of air by the hot pan.

So the difference you are seeing is because the large hot gas flow generated by the gas burner carries the water vapour away and dilutes it before it has a chance to condense.